# How to incrementaly copy the Table Valued Function to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

How can we incrementally copy UDF's from on premise to Azure SQL Database?
We are currently using the SSIS Package to copy the UDF's to Azure SQL Database, its taking approx 8 hours to getting copied, how can we incrementally copy the UDF's to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do. Are you coping UDF definitions or the result of calling a UDF?

Comment: Whats the difference between those two?

Comment: In the case of copying the definitions, it's something like `create funtion` statements. If you're calling them, it's `select * from dbo.yourFunction`. For the former, having to do a significant number of those on an ongoing basis would be a little weird; in the latter, it's a performance timing exercise an we're probably going to need more information.